# Total Number of request in IIS 6

Tags: iis, logging

We have a web server running IIS6 which hosts approximately 100 web sites.  We are looking for a way of monitoring how many requests the web server is handling for a time period, we know we can do this by setting up IIS logging for all of the web sites and then using log parser to merge the results but this is a time consuming process.

What we are really looking for a way of logging the requests centrally is this possible?

Thanks

Neil

UPDATE

I have been having another look around and one of the suggestions is to use the Centralised Binary Logging which looks good, but I'm not sure if it will work in conjunction with the standard IIS logs we are producing for some of our web sites.  Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Performance Counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776490(WS.10).aspx).

Run "perfmon" to launch the Performance Monitor management console. Add counters under the Web Service performance object.

Not recommended to leave it running for long (for performance reasons); pick a limited monitoring period and have it log the data for analysis later.

Comment: Thanks for the response I did have a look at this and while it does have the correct counters a different value is record for each individual website.  Unless I'm going mad it was not possible to get all of the get/post etc requests for the whole of IIS.

Comment: For each counter (like Current Connections), there are _instances_ you can choose to monitor for that counter. Each instance is a web site, but there is also a "_Total" instance.